# AngularJS:ng-pattern has no effect preventin non numeric userinput in input-field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-pattern

I'm trying to prevent non numeric userinput in an inputfield:

```
 <input ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: false}" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
        class="cell large-3"  ng-model="val1" />
```

Unfortunatelly i can input also letters in the input. How I can change this behaviour?

Comment: Patterns usually don't prevent input, they just make it fail validation.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to prevent non numeric userinput in an inputfield

Use `type="number"`:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input type="number" ng-model="value" /><br>
    value={{value}}
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<input type="number"` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)